# Installing google-cloud-vision

Tags: raspberry-pi, pip, google-cloud-platform, raspbian, google-cloud-vision

I'm new to raspberry pi, google cloud, python, somewhat new to linux and would like a suggestion on how to fix/debug this problem.  I'm getting an error when I install the [Cloud Vision API Client Libraries for python](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries).

It seems that this installation breaks pip and pip3 on raspian.  Here's how I reproduced the problem from a fresh install of raspian:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip --version
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud-vision
...
... 
At the end of the log:

  Running setup.py install for dill
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
        import setuptools.version
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pkg_resources
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
        import packaging.version
    ImportError: No module named packaging.version
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-1dbzT3/dill/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lUJmAy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>

    import setuptools.version

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>

    import pkg_resources

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>

    import packaging.version

ImportError: No module named packaging.version
```

Afterwards, when I run pip, I get this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    import packaging.version
ImportError: No module named packaging.version
```

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

Comment: Try Ruby.......

Comment: [Follow this article, very helpful and easy steps](https://www.instructables.com/id/Google-Vision-API-Using-Raspberry-Pi-and-Node/)

Answer (score 0):

There's a trick to installing the cloud client libraries on Raspberry Pi: install virtualenv and sphinx first. The following steps will get you going:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip virtualenv python-dev
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install sphinx
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-vision
python
```